# Why is my slider scrolling? How can I stop it from scrolling?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am doing a website using a free slider from [here](http://www.responsivewebmobile.com/posts/view/2013/12/19/13/Bootstrap_3_Carousel_Fullscreen). I want to use the slider with a nav bar at the top of the page. My problem is, whenever I add the navbar in to the page the slider begins to scroll up and down. If I remove my nav bar everything works fine. When the slider scrolls, only the arrow buttons and the page tabs at the bottom scroll but not the image. My website is [MQMGaming.com](http://mqmgaming.com/). Is there anyway to keep the slider from scrolling so it is the same as without the nav bar?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the navigation itself causing the issue, it's the two br tags you have after the nav ends.  If you remove them it works fine.

Comment: Thanks! This worked! I put the two <br>'s there because I do a PHP include on navbar.php which on other pages, causes an overlap.

Comment: Yea you're better off using styles to move the content down on the other pages so that doesn't happen.  For instance on your About Us page, I put in margin-top:50px on the div that surrounds your h1 (About Us text) and p tags.  EDIT:  Or put the br's just on those pages, either way works :)

Comment: Thanks alot! I am going to try setting the style.